# Index Disadvantages

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-datastore

According to the new update in the pricing policy, there is no more difference, cost wise, in making the properties indexed or not. What is the disadvantages of putting all properties as indexed?

Comment: Indexing typically makes queries faster, but inserts slower

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. You can only search indexed properties - this did not change.
2. If you make every property indexed whether you need them indexed or not, it will slow down the performance of you app when the new entities are added to the Datastore.
3. Indexes take storage space. So making properties unnecessarily indexed will result in higher costs, even though writing to the indexes is now free.